# Variable Defined in Global Scope not accessible in function

Tags: php

This may be a stupid question but I have some code like:

```
$userData = array_map('htmlentities', mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query(
    "SELECT * FROM `smf_members` 
    WHERE `id_member` = (SELECT `id_member` FROM `smf_log_online` WHERE `session` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($session) . "')"
    )));

function printHeader() 
{
    $header = <<<eof
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        ...
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/avatar.gif" alt="" /> {$userData['member_name']}</a>
        ...
eof;
    echo $header;
}
```

That is in a file named `config.php` and is `require`ed in my index page like so:

```
<?php require 'config.php';printHeader(); ?>
```

However inside the `printHeader()` function `$userData` isn't set, where as if I `print_r($userData)` in the global scope it is set. Do I need to put the rest of the "global" code in a constructor of sorts? Or am I missing something really small.

Thanks

Comment: Excuse all the hard to read code, its got a lot of in-lined sanitization!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`global`](http://php.net/global) keyword.

```
$userData = array_map('htmlentities', mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query(
    "SELECT * FROM `smf_members` 
    WHERE `id_member` = (SELECT `id_member` FROM `smf_log_online` WHERE `session` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($session) . "')"
    )));

function printHeader() 
{
            global $userData;

    $header = <<<eof
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        ...
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/avatar.gif" alt="" /> {$userData['member_name']}</a>
        ...
eof;
    echo $header;
}

<?php require 'config.php';printHeader(); ?>
```

Comment: Ahahah thanks! I was just about to answer my own question -.- Shows you should read a bit past the first code examples on the PHP Docs. This solved the issue! :)